# how to change the special port output source address?

Tags: linux, iptables, ip, ip-address

I want to change the my datapackage from port 25 to another internal address(192.168.2.253).

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o em1 -p tcp --dport 25 -j SNAT --to 192.168.2.253
```

But I get the output is:

```
root@gateway:~# iptables -A OUTPUT -o em1 -p tcp --dport 25 -j SNAT --to 192.168.2.253
iptables: Invalid argument. Run `dmesg' for more information.
```

how to do it correctly?

The dmesg output is:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/thinksource/af08acd451380823257b/raw/5d720ce48bcb5ea27699bfcde63e4ccd92e2118c/dmesg%20output

Comment: Well, what did dmesg have to say about it?

Comment: @EEAA please click the link

Comment: What are you exactly wanting to do ? Why rewrite the source address when the destination port is SMTP ?

Comment: @Xavier Lucas there are two ip addresses on the same network adapter one for internal network, one for external network. Actually, I want use the external ip address send emails, while everytime the computer always use the internal ip address.

Answer (score 0):

To add a NAT rule you need to do so in the NAT table; add "-t nat" to the iptables command line.  Further, you can only do SNAT on the INPUT NAT chain (not OUTPUT), and on an inbound interface (-i, not -o).  You will obviously have to alter which interface that is, to the one where the packet is arriving, not the one where it is leaving

Comment: can you tell me how to change the output address?

Comment: The value after --to is what the target address is rewritten to; in your original command, that's 192.168.2.253. Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: You are confusing DNAT and SNAT.

Comment: @Xavier Lucas actually, I have two ip address on same network adapter. I need to use ip 192.168.2.253 to send email, not the other one. do you know how to set it?

Comment: Read my answer ?!

Answer (score 0):

The `SNAT` target is only meaningful in the `POSTROUTING` chain of the nat table.

A valid version of your rule would be :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o em1 -p tcp --dport 25 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.2.253
```

By the way if your (output) interface holds the IP `192.168.2.253`, then rather use :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o em1 -p tcp --dport 25 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: I do not want holds ip address, the simple reason is I have two ip address on one network adapter. I need to use one of them to send email, while every-time the machine always use another one.

Comment: That's exactly what my answer's first rule is doing... I'm giving up on your case, you seem to make no effort at all.

Comment: I can not use nat, since the net address is not assemble by the server.